# Fourier transform of 1/(ax(t)-1) where x(t) is the euler formula

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $x(t)=\exp(i k t)$ where $k$ is a constant

I know the Fourier transform of $x(t)$ is a Dirac function

How can I express the Fourier transform of:

$$\frac{1}{ax(t)-1}$$

where $a=\exp(i b)$, where $b$ is a scalar.

Is there a well known expression for this that I can reference?
If not, can you please guide me to techniques that I can use to derive an expression?

Comment: There's a nice answer below, so perhaps this is fine, but is this really a question about the computing software *Mathematica*, or did you perhaps mean to post this on [math.se]?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the case where $a = 1$:

```
f[t_] = 1/(Exp[I k t]-1);
ft[s_] = FourierTransform[f[t], t, s]
```

> I Sqrt[π/2] Cot[π s/k]/k

Now, your version where $a = e^{i b}$ is equivalent to a translated version of the above, since:

```
1/(Exp[I b]Exp[I k t]-1) == f[t + b/k] //Simplify
```

> True

Unfortunately, Mathematica doesn't do the time translation for us, but it is simple, the Fourier transform satisfies:

```
FourierTransform[f[t - τ], t, s] == Exp[I s τ] FourierTransform[f[t], t, s]
```

So, you're desired transform is:

```
Exp[I s (-b/k)] ft[s]
```

> I E^(- I b s/k) Sqrt[π/2] Cot[π s/k]/k